# Dynamically get web socket URL

Tags: javascript, scala, websocket, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.5 application that uses a web socket. In my Controller I establish it as

```
  def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => TroiWebSocket.props(db, out, comm.communicator, system))
  }
```

And, it's accessed in my routes as

```
GET     /push-notifications         controllers.Application.socket
```

As, currently, my application is running locally, I can reference the socket  in a javascript file using

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/push-notifications");
```

However, I'm starting to move my stuff away from the localhost, and need a way to reference the url in my javascript file. This URL might change (and could be different depending on the development environment). So, how can I reference this URL dynamically? That is, how do I say

```
var socket = new Websocket(URL_OF_WEBSOCKET)
```

I thought of breaking it up in my config files and trying to do it that way, but I'm not so sure that would work.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plain javascript. Declare a File config.js and define some global Object with some config data.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var config = {
     "localWSUrl" : "ws://localhost:9000/socket",
     "wsUrl" : "ws://serverurl.com:443/socket"
   }
  </script>
  <script>
   console.log(config.wsUrl);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

For simplicity sake I wrote everything in one file. You would exclude the config part and import the file via the script tag's src attribute. And then you can reuse it where you need it.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar. I put my different sockets into different config files in my `conf` folder. Then I got it out using `ConfigFactor.load.getConfig("...")`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the URL to get main page of your application is the same or partially same to connect websocket, suppose:
Url app: myapp.com
Websocket url: myapp.com/push-notification
So you could do in your js file using `window.location` of js standard api

`var tcp = window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://';
  var host = window.location.host;
  var path = '/push-notification';
  var ws = new WebSocket(tcp+host+path);`

Something like that..
 I hope It helps.